# Conditional step in a Jenkinsfile launch agent

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to execute a step only when pushing on my `master` branch. That is easily doable with `when`, but this step has to be executed on a different agent, and right now it executes a complete code checkout on the agent before skipping.

I have `agent none` defined at the pipeline level and then each step defines a specific agent. Now, I'd like to skip even trying to launch the agent if the conditions in my `when` means that this step will not be executed. My agent is not always online and it's kindof easy for me to check if it is when I'm pushing to master, but I'd like to not have a failed build when the agent responsible for a skipped stage is offline.

Any idea is welcome to help me.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add beforeAgent to true in the when block
From https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/

> By default, the when condition for a stage will be evaluated after entering the agent for that stage, if one is defined. However, this can be changed by specifying the beforeAgent option within the when block. If beforeAgent is set to true, the when condition will be evaluated first, and the agent will only be entered if the when condition evaluates to true.